# AVAudioSession : microphone headphone as input and iphone speaker as output

Tags: swift, ios10, microphone, avaudiosession, speaker

With iOS10 there are more possibilities to manage AUdioSession, but i couldn't manage to keep the headphone microphone as input while audio is going out through the iphone speaker.

The 'overrideOutputAudioPort' method below also override the input audio port as the iphone microphone

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
  try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
  try! session.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)  
} catch {
}
```

Is there any solution to keep the headphone as input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I undeerstand [this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1618455-audio_session_property_identifie/kaudiosessionproperty_overrideaudioroute?language=objc), this is not possible using `AVAudioSession`:

> If a headset is plugged in at the time you set this property’s value to kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker, the system changes the audio routing for input as well as for output: input comes from the built-in microphone; output goes to the built-in speaker.

Comment: it's not true for the new option "allowBluetoothA2DP" (since iOS10) `try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)` : with this option, the microphone input doesn't change (only the output)

Comment: @DamienRomito interesting. I was not aware of that. Is this documented (beside WWDC video(s))?

Comment: How do you know than?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895832/keep-bluetooth-sound-when-initializing-avaudiosession/39856299#39856299